# Android (Java): Calculate age with the help of DOB and birth time

Tags: java, android, date, time, syntax-error

I have tried it with EditText which will receive value of datepicker and timepicker and will display the birthdate and birth time but now I don't know how to calculate age from the date and time.

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to calculate someone's age by including the local time. As someone's age most likely spans impresice time units (like months, years and even days in case of clock changes due to DST), including precision to the minute doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. **First get today date**

```java
Date today = new Date();
```

2. **Get difference in `time`**

```java
long timeDiff = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
```

3. **Now you can convert time to DATE, MONTH, or YEAR**

```java
int numOfDays = (int) (timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
double years = 0.00273973 * numOfDays;
```

Comment: This won't calculate the numbers correctly if someone's birthday is later this year. Also, don't do the calculations yourself, but use a library wich does the calculations for you.

Comment: @MCEmperor I modified the solution check it now